# Haskell - Searching through a list of pairs

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to make something so that it takes a Book and a string and then returns the value that's associated with the string in the book... so what I have so far is:

```
data Answer = T | F
    deriving (Eq,  Show, Ord)

type Book = [(String, Answer)] 

testBook :: Book
testBook = [("aT", T), ("bF", F)]
```

and I want to do it so that let's say i put:

```
test testBook "aT"
```

^ the answer will come out to T.

i'm doing something like:

```
test::Book->String->Answer
test a b = [x | (y, x) <- a, y == b]
```

but i know that's completely off.. how can I compare the String to what's in the Book?  it seems simple but the syntax for Haskell is really hard to get used to

Comment: Please don't "edit out" your questions. The whole idea of StackOverflow is that other people with the same kind of problem can find the question and the given answers when browsing the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is on the right track. Right now, you get a list of answers *regardless* of the value of `b`. You need to add a condition that checks whether the first item of the tuple is equal to `b`; to do this, you will have to give it a name rather than using `_`.

You can add a condition to a list comprehension by using a comma and an expression:

```
[x | x <- a, x > 10]
```

will get you all the values from `a` greater than 10, for example.

I will let you figure out how to put my advice together yourself.

Comment: that's helpful.  right now i'm trying:

test::Book->String->Answer
test a b = [x | (y, x) <- a, y == b]

which seems right to me.. but i'm getting an error still.  my code (to me) seems like i'm returning x, if the String in the parameter is equal to the first element of the pair

Comment: A list comprehension always returns *a list*. So you're returning a list of answers rather than just one.

Answer (score 3):

Use the "lookup" function (available in Prelude).

Comment: The lookup function is how you would do it in real life, but implementing it yourself is good when you're learning Haskell.

Comment: @TikhonJelvis: Yes and no. I agree that reinventing small wheels is good for getting familiar with Haskell, but Haskell has tons of built-in library functions that are just begging to be used...